# JSF 2 - passing parameters accross system events

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a composite component, where I pass in an arbitrary defined attribute:

```
<x:mycomp x="..."/>
```

`x` being defined as such in the interface definition of the cc. Inside the implementation of `mycomp` I have an event listener:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{mycontroller.init}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Now I would like to do something on the backend with this arbitary parameter `x`. how do I pass it accross the system event, like with an `f:attribute` tag? or getting the source component from the event and trawling through its internals? (speaking of which where in the UIComponent are these attributes stored anyway - I couldn't find them, not in attributes anyway).

If not possible this severely limits the usefulness of system events. If you put the component inside a `ui:repeat` the listener is fired multiple times so it is walking through the tree during event firing.

Only thing I can think of is to encode the init directly into the render:

```
<composite:implementation>
    #{mycontroller.init(cc.attrs.x)} //returns empty string
    <!--f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{mycontroller.init}" /-->
</composite:implementation>
```

But I thought thats what a prerender system event would be for.

Comment: Sorry, I have read your question up to 3 times, but I can't seem to filter/understand the underlying functional requirement. Can you please update your question to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: wow, quick!

i'm passing an attribute into a composite component. assume it has to be decorated in some way before being rendered. can a system event get hold of that attribute 'x' in order to work with it on the server?

same sort of thing as you described in your web site regarding passing parameters through an actionlistener (if you're the same person http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html), except this time its an eventlistener, not an actionlistener.

essentially i'm looking for a way to initialize passed in parameters just before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little late for the answer.

I made a proof of concept of what I think is the problem that you are trying to resolve. In order to make it, you have to take out your event registration and doing it in the using page of your composite. Your init method can receive a ComponentSystemEvent that will give you the composite component and then you could access your 'x' attribute from the map of attributes of the component.

The code in the using page is something like this:

`<x:mycomp x="hola">`
        `<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.init}"/>`
   `</x:mycomp>`

And the java code:

```
public class MyBean {
   private String value;

   public void init(ComponentSystemEvent e){
       System.out.println("x: "+e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("x"));
   }

}
```

I hope it will be useful (some months later).